# Converting a Password Hashing Script from GO to Nodejs

Tags: node.js, go, hash, passwords, sha256

I have a hard time converting an existing GO script to NodeJS. It basically a hashing script which takes in 2 arguments **agreedUponKey** and **salt** and returns a password hash.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "hash"
    "crypto/sha256"
)

func main() {
    var agreedUponKey string
    var salt string
    var h hash.Hash

    agreedUponKey = "giri"
    salt = "XYZabc987"

    h = sha256.New()
    h.Write([]byte(agreedUponKey))
    h.Write([]byte(salt))

    sha256Sum := h.Sum(nil)
    print("calculated passwordHash:", sha256Sum)

    var hexHash = make([]byte, 0, 64)
    for _, v := range sha256Sum {
        hexHash = append(hexHash,[]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%02x", v))...)
    }

    print("calculated passwordHash:", string(hexHash))
}
```

I have managed to code up to the below point

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var convert = require('convert-string');

function test(pwd,key) {
  console.log("Password :",pwd);
  var byteKey=convert.stringToBytes(key);
  var bytePwd=convert.stringToBytes(pwd);    
  var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(byteKey+bytePwd).digest('base64');
  console.log("hashcode of password :",hash);
};
test("XYZabc987","giri");
```

The 2 hashes are different. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am a Noob in GO Lang

Please Note : You can use https://play.golang.org/ to compile and run the Go Script

Comment: You are missing `salt` in the node part.

Comment: test("XYZabc987","giri"); we are sending it as argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
function test(pwd, key) {
    var input = key.concat(pwd)
    var hash = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(input).digest('hex');
    console.log("hashcode of password :", hash);
};
test("XYZabc987", "giri");
```

You could verify the correct hash using this [online tool](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator).

Comment: That helped.. Thanks a Lot!!